# MySQL query returning unexpected results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, one containing information on a city (in a game) and another containing scores as recorded throughout periods of the day. Table examples have been simplified.

```
CREATE TABLE cities(
  cid INT(100),
  name VARCHAR(100),
  updatedAt DATETIME
);
CREATE TABLE cl_scores(
  cid INT(100),
  score INT(255),
  updatedAt DATETIME
);
```

I'm trying to gather a list of scores for a particular city. The list should only contain the MAX(updatedAt) date and score for every day. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT a.cid, b.name, a.score, a.updatedAt FROM ci_scores AS a 
JOIN cities AS b ON a.cid = b.cid 
JOIN (SELECT MAX(updatedAt) AS maxUpdatedAt FROM ci_scores 
GROUP BY DATE(updatedAt)) AS L ON DATE(L.maxUpdatedAt) = DATE(a.updatedAt) 
WHERE a.cid = 10158241 ORDER BY a.updatedAt ASC;
```

However, it isn't returning a single entry for each day. It is in fact returning every row in the ci_scores table and simply adding the name field as shown below:

```
+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| cid      | name    | score | updatedAt           |
+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 10158241 | Genesis |  3087 | 2012-03-13 04:04:03 |
| 10158241 | Genesis |  3207 | 2012-03-13 17:48:56 |
| 10158241 | Genesis |  3255 | 2012-03-14 00:44:11 |
| 10158241 | Genesis |  3262 | 2012-03-14 10:21:05 |
| 10158241 | Genesis |  3262 | 2012-03-14 13:42:42 |
+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
```

What am I doing wrong in my query???

### Solutions Tried

```
SELECT a.cid, b.name, a.score, a.updatedAt FROM ci_scores AS a 
JOIN cities AS b ON a.cid = b.cid 
JOIN (SELECT MAX(updatedAt) AS maxUpdatedAt FROM ci_scores 
GROUP BY DATE(updatedAt) LIMIT 1) AS L ON L.maxUpdatedAt = a.updatedAt
WHERE a.cid = 10158241 ORDER BY a.updatedAt ASC;
```

This did not work, removing the DATE() = DATE() makes it return 0 records as the times are different. If I add that back in it returns:

```
+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| cid      | name    | score | updatedAt           |
+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 10158241 | Genesis |  3087 | 2012-03-13 04:04:03 |
| 10158241 | Genesis |  3207 | 2012-03-13 17:48:56 |
+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
```

This is not correct, I need 1 record for each day and that record being the latest entered on that day.

Comment: You could just add a limit 1:
...
ORDER BY a.updatedAt ASC LIMIT 1;

Comment: What's really not right is that you're introducing twice the ci_scores tables. Therefore in the L subquery, the MAX(updatedAt) is completely unrelated to the city which cid is 10158241. You need to constraint ci_scores.cid in this subquery. Also I believe the join on the DATE(...)=DATE(..) condition is only OK if there is only at most one entry per day per city in ci_scores

Comment: without the DATE() = DATE() it won't return any results as the times are different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should join your subset by updateAT without DATE function

```
SELECT a.cid, b.name, a.score, a.updatedAt FROM ci_scores AS a 
JOIN cities AS b ON a.cid = b.cid 
JOIN (SELECT MAX(updatedAt) AS maxUpdatedAt FROM ci_scores 
GROUP BY DATE(updatedAt)) AS L ON L.maxUpdatedAt = a.updatedAt
WHERE a.cid = 10158241 ORDER BY a.updatedAt ASC;
```

**UPDATE:**
There is another error that in the sub query you need to group by the city id as well so that you can get the correct max date:

```
SELECT a.cid, b.name, a.score, a.updatedAt FROM ci_scores AS a 
JOIN cities AS b ON a.cid = b.cid 
JOIN (SELECT MAX(updatedAt), cid AS maxUpdatedAt FROM ci_scores 
GROUP BY DATE(updatedAt), cid) AS L ON L.maxUpdatedAt = a.updatedAt AND L.cid = a.cid
WHERE a.cid = 10158241 ORDER BY a.updatedAt ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.cid, b.name, a.score, a.updatedAt FROM ci_scores AS a 
JOIN cities AS b ON a.cid = b.cid 
JOIN (SELECT MAX(updatedAt) AS maxUpdatedAt FROM ci_scores 
GROUP BY DATE(updatedAt) LIMIT 1) AS L ON L.maxUpdatedAt = a.updatedAt
WHERE a.cid = 10158241 ORDER BY a.updatedAt ASC;
```

Comment: this breaks the query and it doesn't return any results as the DATE() = DATE() is missing, add that in and I get 2 records but both same day...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.CID, C.NAME, A.updatedAt, A.SCORE FROM cl_scores A
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT D.CID, D.SD, MAX ( S.updatedAt ) MD FROM cl_scores S
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT S.CID, DATE ( S.updatedAt ) SD FROM cl_scores S WHERE S.CID = 10158241) D ON D.CID = S.CID AND D.SD = DATE ( S.updatedAt )
GROUP BY D.CID, D.SD
) B ON B.CID = A.CID AND B.MD = A.updatedAt
INNER JOIN cities C ON C.CID = A.CID
```

The above gives you for the `CID = 10158241` per day (only days present in the table!) the row with the max `updatedAt` and its respective `score`... BEWARE that if you have two rows with the EXACT same `updatedAt` (down to the second...) it might give you more than one row...